# Dell XPS 8950 Ubuntu 22.04 USB Devices Freezing

Tags: usb, 22.04, dell, freeze

Tried asking this previously on the Ubuntu Forums and got no response. I hope I do better here.

Greetings

Running an XPS 8950 and Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS. BIOS is up to date. Kernel is Linux 5.19.0-40-generic x86_64

I have some kind of issue that is causing my machine to freeze. Intervals between vary between three times a day and sometime it can go days without happening. When it does my keyboard and mouse (both USB directly connected) freeze.

The system itself is still running - I can see chats changing on my screen but there is no keyboard, mouse or camera (USB as well).

When I look in /var/log/syslog I see thousands of entries like this below.

```
Apr 13 16:36:37 nigel-xps kernel: [ 2663.336234] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Frame ID 1434 (reg 11495, index 7) beyond range (1438, 283)
Apr 13 16:36:37 nigel-xps kernel: [ 2663.336240] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Ignore frame ID field, use SIA bit instead
Apr 13 16:36:37 nigel-xps kernel: [ 2663.336243] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Frame ID 1435 (reg 11495, index 8) beyond range (1438, 283)
Apr 13 16:36:37 nigel-xps kernel: [ 2663.336246] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Ignore frame ID field, use SIA bit instead
Apr 13 16:36:37 nigel-xps kernel: [ 2663.336248] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Frame ID 1435 (reg 11495, index 9) beyond range (1438, 283)
Apr 13 16:36:37 nigel-xps kernel: [ 2663.341276] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Ignore frame ID field, use SIA bit instead
Apr 13 16:36:37 nigel-xps kernel: [ 2663.341278] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Frame ID 1435 (reg 11536, index 10) beyond range (1443, 289)
Apr 13 16:36:37 nigel-xps kernel: [ 2663.341279] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Ignore frame ID field, use SIA bit instead
Apr 13 16:36:37 nigel-xps kernel: [ 2663.341282] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Frame ID 1435 (reg 11536, index 11) beyond range (1443, 289)
Apr 13 16:36:37 nigel-xps kernel: [ 2663.341284] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Ignore frame ID field, use SIA bit instead
Apr 13 16:36:37 nigel-xps kernel: [ 2663.341285] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Frame ID 1435 (reg 11536, index 12) beyond range (1443, 289)
Apr 13 16:36:37 nigel-xps kernel: [ 2663.341287] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Ignore frame ID field, use SIA bit instead
Apr 13 16:36:37 nigel-xps kernel: [ 2663.341289] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Frame ID 1435 (reg 11536, index 13) beyond range (1443, 289)
Apr 13 16:36:37 nigel-xps kernel: [ 2663.341290] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Ignore frame ID field, use SIA bit instead
Apr 13 16:36:37 nigel-xps kernel: [ 2663.341292] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Frame ID 1435 (reg 11536, index 14) beyond range (1443, 289)
Apr 13 16:36:37 nigel-xps kernel: [ 2663.341293] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Ignore frame ID field, use SIA bit instead
Apr 13 16:36:37 nigel-xps kernel: [ 2663.341295] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Frame ID 1435 (reg 11536, index 15) beyond range (1443, 289)
Apr 13 16:36:37 nigel-xps kernel: [ 2663.341296] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Ignore frame ID field, use SIA bit instead
Apr 13 16:36:37 nigel-xps kernel: [ 2663.341298] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Frame ID 1436 (reg 11536, index 16) beyond range (1443, 289)
```

lsusb is reporting this:

```
dna@nigel-xps:~/Desktop$ lsusb -tv
/: Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/9p, 20000M/x2
ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
/: Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
|__ Port 7: Dev 2, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
ID 046d:082d Logitech, Inc. HD Pro Webcam C920
|__ Port 7: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
ID 046d:082d Logitech, Inc. HD Pro Webcam C920
|__ Port 7: Dev 2, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
ID 046d:082d Logitech, Inc. HD Pro Webcam C920
|__ Port 7: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
ID 046d:082d Logitech, Inc. HD Pro Webcam C920
|__ Port 8: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
ID 1b1c:1b3c Corsair
|__ Port 8: Dev 3, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=, 12M
ID 1b1c:1b3c Corsair
|__ Port 8: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
ID 1b1c:1b3c Corsair
|__ Port 9: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
ID 0b05:17f5 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. Xonar U5 sound card
|__ Port 9: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
ID 0b05:17f5 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. Xonar U5 sound card
|__ Port 9: Dev 4, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
ID 0b05:17f5 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. Xonar U5 sound card
|__ Port 9: Dev 4, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
ID 0b05:17f5 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. Xonar U5 sound card
|__ Port 9: Dev 4, If 4, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 480M
ID 0b05:17f5 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. Xonar U5 sound card
|__ Port 10: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
ID 1b1c:1b3d Corsair Corsair Corsair Gaming K55 RGB Keyboard
|__ Port 10: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
ID 1b1c:1b3d Corsair Corsair Corsair Gaming K55 RGB Keyboard
|__ Port 14: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
ID 8087:0032 Intel Corp. AX210 Bluetooth
|__ Port 14: Dev 6, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
ID 8087:0032 Intel Corp. AX210 Bluetooth
```

and lspci shows this:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4668 (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake Innovation Platform Framework Processor Participant (rev 02)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x4 Controller #0 (rev 02)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor Gaussian & Neural Accelerator (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 7ae0 (rev 11)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 7aa7 (rev 11)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Device 7acc (rev 11)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Device 7acd (rev 11)
00:15.2 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Device 7ace (rev 11)
00:15.3 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Device 7acf (rev 11)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 7ae8 (rev 11)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 7ae2 (rev 11)
00:19.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Device 7afc (rev 11)
00:19.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Device 7afd (rev 11)
00:1a.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7ac8 (rev 11)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7ac3 (rev 11)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7abc (rev 11)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7abf (rev 11)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 7aa8 (rev 11)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7a84 (rev 11)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 7ad0 (rev 11)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 7aa3 (rev 11)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Device 7aa4 (rev 11)
01:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 XL Upstream Port of PCI Express Switch (rev c5)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 XL Downstream Port of PCI Express Switch
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 22 [Radeon RX 6700/6700 XT / 6800M] (rev c5)
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 21 HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 6800/6800 XT / 6900 XT]
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Kingston Technology Company, Inc. Device 500f (rev 03)
05:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller PM9A1/PM9A3/980PRO
06:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Killer E3000 2.5GbE Controller (rev 06)
08:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz (rev 1a)
```

Syslog is getting a sh*tload of data pumped into it - around 90,000 lines per day.

Anyone have any suggestions where to start looking please?

Thanks

Nigel.

Comment: I'd have found [a link to the post of UF helpful](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2485914); there is no mention of what 22.04 product, thus no clue as to kernel stack in use here, and it may have been mentioned at UF...   As you can try different kernel stacks with *live* media; I find them helpful in exploring some conditions like this....  (*if you're not using closed source kernel modules; multiple kernel stacks can co-exist on the same install too*)

Comment: Not quite sure how a link to the exact same question might have helped. Have now updated to show the Kernel in use.

Comment: Curiously enough, I have discovered that the issue does not appear to be limited to the current kernel. But if I unplug my Asus Xonar U5 USB sound card all the errors mysteriously disappear. Off to the shops.